# Using Require with React in a web page without node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, browserify

I know this might be a silly question to some of you, but I am beginner in React, and I wish to create a really simple application.
I found a sample in which every component is saved in a separate js file, which looks very good for modularity and re-usage.

The only thing I need to take care of now is using export/require. However, I don't need to be dependent on nodejs. I just need a simple html/js application that can run on any cheap web server.

I read somewhere that I can use "Browserify", but after looking at it, it seems like a node library.

Is there any library that I can use from a web page (via cdn for example) that allow me to use require? If not, does that mean I can not separate react components in different files?

Comment: For export or require you dont need nodeJS, you just need requireJs which is a module loader..

Comment: Do you have a simple example of how to use it with react?

Answer (score 4):

> However, I don't need to be dependent on nodejs.

Use NodeJS. It is how React applications are designed to be built.

> I just need a simple html/js application that can run on any cheap web server

NodeJS is only required at *build* time. You run it on your development workstation. The output is static files that you can upload to any webserver.

(NB: React applications are often designed to make HTTP requests to get dynamic data. Some tutorials cover using Node to build a server to listen for and make responses to those requests. Make sure you don't conflate the program to transpile the React application to ES5 (which runs at build time) with the program to run a webserver (at runtime) even if both are written using Node).

Comment: Interesting! So you're saying I only need Node in dev environment, which is something I don't mind. But What tool should i use to generate the output? Also does that mean I will end up having dev copy and production copy?

Comment: @Lamar — The ones recommended in the tutorial, perhaps? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#enabling-es6-and-jsx

Comment: @Lamar — You'll have some ES6/JSX source code which you transpile to ES5 which you run in the browser in dev / staging / live / whatever other environments you may or may not have.

Comment: Sorry I meant I will end up having a production packed version, which is difference from multiple-files development version. I kind of wished I could do something easier for development that allows me fix and check directly without packaging.

Comment: @Lamar — That's why people use tools like Grunt: To transpile on when the files are changed. You can't check directly without transpiling, because the browser doesn't understand JSX.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks for the information. However, isn't Babel enough for run time transpiling. My basic react/jsx code works perfectly just by including babel.. Sorry if I sound ignorant, I'm really newbie here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Node, you can use webpack: https://webpack.github.io/
you will generate a `static/bundle.js` . If you want to learn more about it, I sugest http://survivejs.com/

Comment: "Before getting started, make sure you have a fresh version of Node.js installed" — https://webpack.js.org/get-started/install-webpack/ — It isn't a very good solution if you don't want to use Node!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a build step that packs the separate files into one or more packages that can be loaded in the browser.
Browserify can be used to do that, but WebPack is also popular.

These tools require some configuration, so I think that the best way to start is with a tool like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which is easy to install and has commands for developing as well as packing your app for deployment.

It uses webpack internally (along with some other tools) but saves you the hassle of configuring it yourself. If at any time you need advanced configurations beyond what create-react-app provides, it has an 'eject' command that exposes the raw configuration files.

Getting started is simple (taken from their readme):

```
npm install -g create-react-app  

create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```